# mod_rewrite directory heirarchy, rules specific to rewritten URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have directories and subdirectories similar to below:

```
Each file and folder here is preceded by localhost/dir/
/common/style.css
/common/js.js
/common/top.php
/common/bottom.php
/images/items/1.png
/images/items/2.png
/images/items/3.png
/index.php
/items.php
/specificitem.php
```

On every page in the default directory, everything in the common folder is included (each page includes `top.php` and `bottom.php`, `top.php` includes `js.js` and `style.css`). `specificitem.php` relies on `$_GET` to grab data to populate that page, and is directed to from `items.php`.

In my `.htaccess` file, I rewrite the URLs for `specificitem.php` like the below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule items/john specificitem.php?id=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule items/jane specificitem.php?id=2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule items/jill specificitem.php?id=3 [NC,L]
...
```

When directing to these pages, no links work, styling and Javascript are broken/not loaded. Links are in the form `./somelink.php`, and when on one of the item pages (eg. `localhost/dir/items/john`), `./somelink.php` tries to direct to `localhost/dir/items/somelink.php` when this page doesn't exist. Stylesheets and Javascript are also attempted to be found at `localhost/dir/items/common/` when likewise this doesn't exist. Changing the links to `/somelink.php` instead tries to go to `/localhost/somelink.php` when this doesn't exist.

What have I done wrong in my `.htaccess` file, or what is missing such that I can apply link rules to rewritten links only? My links, extra files, images are loaded properly for any page without a rewritten URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^items/john/?$ specificitem.php?id=1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^items/jane/?$ specificitem.php?id=2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^items/jill/?$ specificitem.php?id=3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then to fix links/css/js/images paths you need to add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/dir/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.